# OGV file not playing. Mime type set, checked Curl, tried to disable GZIP on server

Tags: html

I have followed numerous posts for the last two days. Firefox won't play the OGV file on [this link](http://www.beautiful-soul.co.uk/collections/aw11.php), but works fine on the local server. The file is `chmod 777`.

This is in the `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
RewriteRule . - [E=no-gzip:0]

<FilesMatch "^(?!.*\.ogg$|.*\.ogv$).+" >
    <IfModule filter_module>
        FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE env=notogg true
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /text/(html|css|javascript|plain|x(ml|-component))/
        FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /application/(javascript|json|xml|x-javascript)/
        FilterChain     COMPRESS
        FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  change=yes;byteranges=no
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

AddType audio/ogg .oga .ogg
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType application/ogg .ogg
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

I have this at the top of the page:

```
<?php ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); ?>
```

This is the code:

```
<video width="720" height="405" controls autoplay preload >     
    <source src="beautiful_soul_aw111.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="beautiful_soul_aw11.m4v" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="beautiful_soul_aw11.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    <source src="beautiful_soul_aw11.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

When I do `phpinfo` I see that the server is ignoring my request to switch gzip off.

I checked using curl and the file is being served as the correct type:

```
curl -I http://www.beautiful-soul.co.uk/collections/beautiful_soul_aw11.ogv
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 29 Aug 2011 18:44:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Aug 2011 17:44:49 GMT
ETag: "36976a8-4aba873976640"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 57243304
Content-Type: video/ogg
```

When I look at the page and get the page information, it shows this:

```
Location: http://www.beautiful-soul.co.uk/collections/beautiful_soul_aw11.ogv
Type: video/ogg
Size: 8 KB (8192 bytes)
Dimensions: 0px × 0px
Associated Text: AC_FL_RunContent(...
```

I do not know why.

1. My `.htaccess` file would be ignored and GZIP is still enabled.
2. Why the OGV file is found but is only downloaded in Bytes and has no dimensions.

Comment: Seems like this was solved (in my Firefox I see only one `<source>` (ogv) inside the `<video>` and it plays fine). Care to post the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah sorry for the late reply. I re-installed/updated firefox. This was solved by taking out the ogg version

```
<video width="720" height="405"  preload controls autoplay >

    <source src="beautiful_soul_aw111.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="beautiful_soul_aw11.m4v" type='video/mp4' />
    <!--<source src="beautiful_soul_aw11.ogv" type='video/ogg' />-->
    <source src="beautiful_soul_aw11.webm" type='video/webm' />
 </video>
```

It plays fine in all the browsers now.

Thanks

Andi